# Customization of Django admin page to add button

Tags: django, admin, customization

I want to add additional button in the admin page other than save , delete and save and continue button.I do know that I should change the default page of admin but I couldn't able to implement it.I can understand it theortically but not in practical.I want steps to change the default program of Django admin page.I need a demo for it.I need a little brief explaination.

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far...? Any code you want to share ?

Answer (score 0):

go to your site packages directory then to django then contrib then admin and then templates. There you will find all the templates. Copy the templates, and then in your command line type manage.py collectstatics, now you have your admin templates and your admin statics files. You can modify this button

Comment: STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')

Comment: I added the above code in settings.py but I'm getting error like this.

Comment: WindowsError: [Error 3] The system cannot find the path specified: u'C:\\Users\\Prasanna Vasudevan\\Desktop\\Django\\Assignment\\static\\*.*'

Comment: did you copy the folders of the admin templates, to your template folder?. are your templates working fine?

Comment: No not so. Its not working for me.What shall I do to make it working?

Comment: {% extends "admin/base.html" %}

{% block title %}{{ title }} | {{ "HUHA"|default:_('Django site admin') }}{% endblock %}

{% block branding %}
<h1 id="site-name"><a href="{% url 'admin:index' %}">Administrator</a></h1>
<div class="row>
  <button type="submit" style="width:500px">YETANOTHERBUTTON</button>
 </div>
{% endblock %}

{% block nav-global %}{% endblock %}                                                                  I tried this but its not reflecting in my admin page.My file path is projrct/template/admin/base_site.html

Comment: Yeah its working.I could able to customize the admin header using admin.site.site_header=" " but using base_site.html I could not able to customize it. The changes made in base_site.html do not have any effect in django admin page.

Comment: Isn't necessary extend, just find the template and delete the save and continue editing button

Comment: I created a folder project/templates/admin and then I created base.html where I copied the code from https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/base.html and run my server but there is no change in it.I also created base_site.html and tried changing the admin header but it is not responding. what shall I do?